How do I get the Unifi USG to adopt the hardware
I used to have a Unifi USG and a cloudkey in my rack.  I upgraded to the dream machine which went smoother than I expected.  I have now sold the house, as part of the chattels I specified the USG.

I have put the USG back in.  I had thought that maybe I could do a restore of the UDM-Pros backup.  But the USG is on a local account and the UDM-Pro is on a cloud account.
Since I had the USG before, I just had to update a few port forwarding rules and names of a few new machines.  It's all working.
But, the Cloudkey tells me that No Unify Devices have been adopted
For each device (routers, switches and WAPs) I do a Force Provision.  It goes through the motions but nothing changes.

How do I get the Cloudkey to adopt the devices?
When I google, its talking about adopting new devices.  In this case, I have existing devices.
I had a suggestion to plug back the UDM-Pro and remove the devices.  But I had looked at that already. The warning is that you lose all the settings, so I didn't do it.
I would have thought that the word Force implies that you do it anyway.

Have you made sure the USG is running the same version of Unifi Network? New to UniFi, but I am trying to finding out, if everything is running on the same version

Not sure, unless i plug the UDM back in.  Its already in my suitcase to take to Australia.  But everything is always at the latest versions.

I heard back from support that I have to factory rest each device, which will then get adopted and the controller will push out its configuration.
This is fine, except my devices, especially the WAP are in not in easily reachable places.  Another way to do is (with help from unifi forums).

Select the Device in the controller
Select the Tools tab (not the Setup)
If Debug Terminal is not visible then Scroll down and press on Debug Terminal
Click on Open Terminal (beats SSHing into each with putty)
In the console type in set-inform http://192.168.1.230/inform
Close the Debug Terminal
Close the Device Tab
Restart the Device

Note my controller is situated at 192.168.1.230.
